How can I create a multi-job GitHub Actions workflow with secrets?
I would like to create a multi-job GitHub Actions workflow to lint and test my python code, lint my Dockerfile, then build and push my docker image to my Docker Hub only if the pytest, pylint, and hadolint workflows finish successfully. I managed to do this in a single job using the following workflow:
name: Github Actions

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        make install
    - name: Lint with pylint
      run: |
        make lint
    - name: Test with pytest
      env:
        DEVELOPER_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_KEY }}
      run: |
        make test

    - name: Dockerfile linting
      uses: hadolint/hadolint-action@v3.1.0
      with:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile

    - name: Build and Push Docker Image
      uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v6
      with:
        image: stevenherrera/youtube-comment-microservice
        tags: v1, latest
        registry: docker.io
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

I created a separate dev branch and attempted to convert this to a multi-job workflow to take advantage of parallelism using the following:
name: Dev CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  lint_and_test:
    name: Pylint and pyest microservice
    uses: ./.github/workflows/job_lint_test_microservice.yml

  hadolint:
    name: Hadolint Dockerfile
    uses: ./.github/workflows/job_hadolint_dockerfile.yml

  build_and_push_img:
    name: Docker Build and Push
    needs: [lint_and_test, hadolint]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/job_build_push_img.yml

However, the pytesting portion fails with the following error message:
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found.
Which I find odd since the first workflow is able to find my repository secrets and does not receive this error. I have provided a link to the relevant repository here so you can see more details. Please tell me how I can rewrite this workflow into a multi-job build that accomplishes what the first workflow does.
Many thanks.

After some tinkering I got the following to work:
name: Dev CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  pylint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: make install

    - name: Lint Python code with pylint
      run: make lint

  pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: make install

    - name: Test Python code with pytest
      env:
        DEVELOPER_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_KEY }}
      run: make test

  hadolint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Dockerfile linting with hadolint
      uses: hadolint/hadolint-action@v3.1.0
      with:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile

  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [pylint, pytest, hadolint]
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Build and Push Docker Image
      uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v6
      with:
        image: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/youtube-comment-microservice
        tags: v1, latest
        registry: docker.io
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You needed secrets: inherit when calling each re-useable workflow.
  lint_and_test:
    name: Pylint and pyest microservice
    uses: ./.github/workflows/job_lint_test_microservice.yml
    secrets: inherit

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit
